# Problem calling the pop-up window & 'variable' is not declared

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a question about calling the pop-up registration ..

I want to correct the error for me regarding the pop-up window in my code ..

how can I call it in the VB code correctly to send email ?

And also show me this message " variable' is not declared" in the text boxes ..

What is the problem here?

Code as follows:

```js
VB.net Code : 

Protected Sub selectbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        mpe.Show()

    End Sub



    Protected Sub SendEmail(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim EnglishName As String = TryCast(RepeaterCourse.FindControl("lblEnglishName"), Label).Text
        Dim ArabicName As String = TryCast(RepeaterCourse.FindControl("lblCourseArabicTitle"), Label).Text
        Dim StartCourse As String = TryCast(RepeaterCourse.FindControl("lblStartCours"), Label).Text
        Dim EndCourse As String = TryCast(RepeaterCourse.FindControl("lblEndCourse"), Label).Text
        Dim Days As String = TryCast(RepeaterCourse.FindControl("lblDays"), Label).Text
        Dim CityCountry As String = TryCast(RepeaterCourse.FindControl("lblCountry"), Label).Text

        Dim TextName As String = TextName.text

        Dim body As String = "Email: " + TextBoxEmail.Text + "<br>" + "Name: " + TextBoxEnglishName.Text + "<br>" + "Country: " + DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString + "<br>" + "City: " + TextBoxCityName.Text + "<br>" + "Phone: " + TextBoxPhone.Text + "<br>" + "Category: " + DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue + "<br>" + "<br>" + "<br>" + "Message: " + TextComment.Text + "<br>" + hfEnglishName.Value
        Dim mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        mail.[To].Add("noor@gmail.com")
        mail.Bcc.Add("noor@gmail.com")
        mail.From = New MailAddress("noor@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "From Inhouse Training ....By "
        mail.Body = body
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net")
        smtp.EnableSsl = False
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp.Send(mail)
        LabelMSG.Text = "Sent Successfully"
        ClearFields()
    End Sub
```

```html
<div id ="container">

         <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel2" updatemode="Conditional"> 
                      
<ContentTemplate>

    <div class="row">

   <div class="container">        

         <div style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 10px;font-size: 16px;color: brown;"><asp:Label ID="lblmsg" Text="Registration Successful" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:Label></div>

     
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function HideLabel() {
                 var seconds = 5;
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     document.getElementById("<%=lblmsg.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
                 }, seconds * 1000);
             };
    </script>

      
          <div class="courses-listing clearfix" style="margin-bottom:30px;">

    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCourse" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>    
           

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 column threecol">


        <div class="course-preview premium-course">


 <div class="course-image">

        <asp:Label ID="CourseLogo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseLogo")%>'></asp:Label>

        
       <%-- <div class="course-price product-price">
   <div class="price-text"><span class="amount">$128</span></div>
   <div class="corner-wrap">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner-background"></div>
   </div>   
  </div>--%>

        
  <div class="course-meta">

  <header class="course-header">

   <h5 class="nomargin"><asp:Label ID="lblEnglishName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EnglishName")%>'></asp:Label></h5>

            <br />

<%--            <span style="color: #777; font-size: 0.9em;">innovative tool to streamline the instructional design process.</span> <br />--%>
            <h5 class="Arabic-Name"><asp:Label ID="lblCourseArabicTitle" runat="server" data-class="hide" Text='<%# Eval("ArabicName")%>'></asp:Label></h5>
            
            <br />

           <p class="author"> 
                     <asp:Label ID="lblStartCourse" data-class="hide" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartCourse", "{0:dd MMM}")%>'></asp:Label> - 
                <asp:Label ID="lblEndCourse" runat="server" data-class="hide" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EndCourse" , "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
                | <asp:Label ID="lblDays" runat="server" data-class="hide" Text='<%# Eval("Days")%>'></asp:Label>  Days                                          </p>


            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" data-class="hide" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CityCountry")%>'></asp:Label>

     </header>

            <br />


    <div class="course-footer clearfix">

<%--                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="SavePDF" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("BrochoreLink")%>'  class="sim-button button14" style="line-height: 20px; color:white;">Download Brochore</asp:LinkButton>--%>
             
                    <asp:Button ID="selectbtn" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="selectbtn_Click1"  class="sim-button button14" style="line-height: 20px; color:white;"></asp:Button>

<%--                    <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectGo" runat="server" Text="Select" ItemStyle-Width="100" CommandName="Select"  class="sim-button button14" style="line-height: 20px; color:white;">Register</asp:LinkButton>--%>

                      <a class="sim-button button14" style="line-height: 20px; color:white;" href='/Brochures/<%# Eval("BrochoreLink")%>' target="_blank" ><span>Download Brochore</span></a>
<%--                      <a class="sim-button button14" style="line-height: 20px; color:white;" href="http://store.cglobalc.com/?page_id=1191"><span></span>Register</a>--%>
                      <a class="sim-button button14" style="line-height: 20px; color:white;" href="InHouseTraining.aspx" target="_blank"><span>Run This Course In-House</span></a>


                    
    
 </div> 


         

  </div>


         </div>


             </div>


                    <asp:LinkButton Text="" ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkFake"
        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>


<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" Class="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
    <div class="footer" align="right" style="float: right;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="x" Style="margin: 2px;
            font-size: 22px; color: white; background: none; border: none; border-color: none;
            border-radius: 0px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-header">
            <p style="font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
                margin: 0 0 0.1em 0; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                CONTACT US
            </p>
            <p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 1.25em; margin: 1em 0 0.4em 0;">
                Fill out the form below to complete register!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="login-form">
            <p class="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Full Name" CssClass="login-label"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server" placeholder="Your Name" class="input"></asp:TextBox>
                
                <br />

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="Register"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" Forecolor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                
                <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                 ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" ErrorMessage="Only character" 
                 ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+" Display="dynamic" Forecolor="red" Font-Size ="Small"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
            </p>


            <p style="float: right;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Email" CssClass="login-label"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" placeholder="Example@gmail.com" class="input"></asp:TextBox>
                
                <br />

                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valRegEx" ValidationGroup="Register" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ValidationExpression=".*@.*\..*" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Email address."
                    Display="dynamic" Forecolor="red" Font-Size ="Small">
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Register"
                    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </p>


            <p class="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Country" CssClass="login-label"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCityName" runat="server" placeholder="Your Country" class="input"></asp:TextBox>
                
                 <br />

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="Register"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBoxCityName" Forecolor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           
                <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                 ControlToValidate="TextBoxCityName" ErrorMessage="Only character" 
                 ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+" Display="dynamic" Forecolor="red" Font-Size ="Small"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
            </p>


            <p style="float: right;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Phone Number" CssClass="login-label"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPhone" runat="server" placeholder="Your Phone" class="input"></asp:TextBox>

                     <br />

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ValidationGroup="Register"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPhone" ValidateEmptyText="true"
                    ValidationExpression="^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*)$" Forecolor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RxvMobile" ValidationGroup="Register"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="just number" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPhone" ValidateEmptyText="false"
                    ValidationExpression="^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*){5,9}$" Forecolor="red" Display="Dynamic" Font-Size ="Small"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            </p>


            <p class="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Comment" CssClass="login-label"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxComment" runat="server" placeholder="Notes" TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Rows="4" class="login-textarea"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </p>


            <p>
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="Register" runat="server"
                    Text="Register" CommandName="Select" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="SendEmail"
                    Style="cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: none; margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto; display: block; vertical-align: top;" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

          

 </asp:Panel>


       


            </div>


     


        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
            


             </ContentTemplate>

  <Triggers>


                            </Triggers>



</asp:UpdatePanel>

                </div>
```

Thank you ..

Comment: Can you identify where the error was coming from? Did you have problems with `RepeaterCourse.FindControl()` method?

Comment: Yes .. I knew the problem was solved for the pop-up window .. I had a problem with the order of the code .. but for the call of RepeaterCourse.FindControl() to send it by email , I did not know the right way :( ..